# WPF or GTK ? which one is better

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gtk

I'm going to start a new project with WPF, during last week I read much about it and found it quite useful. But recently I got familiar with GTK whichis Open and have most of WPF abilities.

Which one is better (in common) and is GTK a better choise for me or not?

I use .NET and my clients are using Windows (XP sp2 and above).

Comment: GTK+/Gtk# has most of WPF's abilities? How do you know? Where did you read about this?

Comment: @BoltClock, by the `Most` I meant that most of thing I need to implement my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use GTK on windows because windows is my favorite development platform but in production code GTK is only used on Unix (Linux/FreeBSD) platforms. Its just to bad for production code on Windows7. The umlaute key bugs were already mentionend so like to add the problems with popup windows and focus events.

Also despite it is called multiplattform on the GTK webpage the team does not care too much about Windows and MacOSX. This hostile attitude makes it much more worse and dangerous to use code. A good sign is that they simply don't came up with an easy to compile VS2010 environment. I don't understand whats so difficult to write simple makefiles.

On Windows there is no chance other then using WPF or MFC. And on MacOSX you have to use Cocoa. Windows7 and Cocoa both deprecated large parts of the theming engine, which means (and this is an explicit strategic goal) developers must use the platform GUI toolkit in the long term.

Comment: Well, not really correct, there is a chance, but it wouldn't be wise.

Comment: It's not that they are hostile to Windows or MacOSX, it's just that it's a community project, and that Windows or OSX people just don't step up to do the work. The GNOME guys are doing most of the work, and just don't have the time, the resources, or the knowledge to take the whole burden. The situation could improve if a Windows guy steps up to do the work, but otherwise, the Windows version of GTK 3 will remain clunky.

Answer (score 3):

> ...But recently I got familiar with
>   GTK whichis Open and have most of WPF
>   abilities.

Hm, I doubt if this statement would persist a thorough analysis. WPF implements many features and abilities which are considered to be implemented by GTK some day, but if you mind waiting...

> I use .NET and my clients are using
>   Windows (XP sp2 and above).

What? You are using .NET and consider using other presentation front-ends then those which are already perfectly integrated with the platform? That I don't understand. I assume you really mean .NET (i.e. the Microsoft implementation of CLR/CLS specification).

Answer (score 1):

I had various problems with GTK because keyboard support is not trully working on Windows. Umlauts etc... are not recognized correctly. Happens in every GTK application I've on Windows, so it's not only in my application.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371371

Because of this, GTK is never option for me on Windows (can't even use my own applications then).

WPF in contrast tries to split some tasks much more then GTK is able to. Means a designer and a programmer should be able to better split their work.

Comment: Yeah, GTK+ and WPF are two entirely different toolkits (I don't even know if WPF can be classified as a toolkit). And WPF is much more than just UI, despite the letter P.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get clear about your question by googling.

I think you must refer this. links.

http://www.stealthstartupblog.com/?p=23
http://trader.mikaelaldridge.com/uncategorized/wpf-vs-gtk/